# BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App/Task::belonsTo()'

Tags: php

when I am executing the below's code to get the project details belongs to the first task in the array.

```
App\Task::first()->project
```

I am getting exception below:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method
>   App/Task::belonsTo()'

I've tried this code too:
App\Task::first()->project()

I expect the output like this:

```
App\Project {#2928
     id: 1,
     title: "My First Project changed",
     description: "lorem ipsum changed..",
     created_at: "2019-04-12 11:00:23",
     updated_at: "2019-04-13 11:15:57",
   }
```

Comment: It looks like a typo, didn't you use `belonsTo()` instead of `belongsTo()` in `first` function? If not the case, you should share the code for `App\Task::first()` (in the question itself, using the edit link), because we can't guess what's going on

Comment: I have corrected the typo.

App\Task::first()->project
after executing the code above code the result is coming null.
like this:
=> null

Comment: I suggest you take the [tour] and read the [ask] page, in particular "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.". We can't help you if you don't share the part of code where this is happening